# How to read a sms reply after I sent an SMS in Twilio dashboard?

Tags: twilio

Is there any dashboard tool in Twilio to read an SMS reply after I sent an SMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so first go to your twilio console

then on the left sidebar there's two things side by side Develop / Monitor

click on Monitor and then click on Logs then Messaging. Here you can see all sent and received messages.

in short:
Twilio Console> Monitor > Logs > Messaging

Answer (score 0):

You will need to monitor the message logs in the twilio console.